# NIFI : ConvertJSONToSQL config for timestamp column

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi, datetime-format

I want to insert json record to oracle table with Nifi and some of the columns type in table are timestamp. how can I determine timestamp columns in sql statement.

here is the output of processor:

[image]

here is table schema:

[image]

here is timestamp format in content:

"timestamp": "Mon, 04.04.2022 02:17:09"

Comment: If the input is JSON, and attribute `"timestamp"` is supposed to hold a timestamp value, why isn't the value in standard format? It looks like a string instead, in some non-standard format. The proper way to solve this problem is to work with the provider of the JSON, asking them to provide the timestamp in standard format (which is, for your example, `2022-04-04 02:17:09'` - without day-of-the-week component). Then the JSON/SQL functions will have no problem converting the value to a proper timestamp.

Comment: I converted it to standard format (2022-04-04 02:17:09.000') and it's worked.thanks for your tip

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this can help you out. You can add to the not in clause as needed.

```
select col.owner as schema_name,
       col.table_name,
       column_id,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       data_scale as second_scale
from sys.dba_tab_cols col
join sys.dba_tables tab on col.owner = tab.owner
                        and col.table_name = tab.table_name
where (data_type in ('DATE')
      or col.data_type like 'TIMESTAMP%' 
      or col.data_type like 'INTERVAL%')
      and col.owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
order by col.owner,
         col.table_name,
         column_id;
```